# Run JS when show a certain section on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JavaScript **TypingText.js** that executes "typing text", however, I need to run JavaScript "typing text" when a user scrolls to the section where that text is located. Can anyone help me?

```html
<section id="mysection">
<div id="example1">My text here</div>
</section>        
        
<script type="text/javascript">
// Flag to execute the function only once
let typeTextStarted = false;

// Get the section<s position in the document
let mysectionPosition = $("#mysection").offset()

// Get the view port height
let viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  // If scrolled position is more than the section's position MINUS the viewport height
  if ($(this).scrollTop()>mysectionPosition.top - viewportHeight && !typeTextStarted) {

    // Set flag
    typeTextStarted = true;

    new TypingText(document.getElementById("example1"));
    TypingText.runAll();
  }
});     
</script>
```

Comment: Do you close the `section` tag? Do you use jQuery?

Comment: Uhhh no, please help me, how to do that. I closed my section tag, but jQuery, i dont know

Comment: add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` at the end of your `head` tag

Comment: You **do not** use jQuery? Then why the jQuery tag on your question? Use the CDN Abdullah provided... And please, have a look at [jQuery learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/) before asking further questions.

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette and Abdullah Abid THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to detect when the section is visible. So a bit of calculations are required. That is:

1. To get the section's position in the document
2. To get the viewport height
3. On scroll, get the scrolled position

Then, using a flag, run the function once...

Tested on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=0011)

```
// Flag to execute the function only once
let typeTextStarted = false;

// Get the section<s position in the document
let mysectionPosition = $("#mysection").offset()

// Get the view port height
let viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  // If scrolled position is more than the section's position MINUS the viewport height
  if ($(this).scrollTop()>mysectionPosition.top - viewportHeight && !typeTextStarted) {

    // Set flag
    typeTextStarted = true;

    new TypingText(document.getElementById("example1"));
    TypingText.runAll();
  }
});
```

Comment: I just tried what you told me, but unfortunately it won't work,  also now not working typing effect

Comment: You are right... I was wrong with `:visible`... I changed my answer. ;)

Comment: `won't work` does not help me... Are you using jQuery?

Comment: In detail as you said, I copied your entire code and nothing happens! :(

Comment: mmm... Edit your question with the code and markup you actually have. Use a snippet (the `<>` button in the editor). And make sure it behaves like what you have locally.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it now works with the jQuery CDN added. ;)